# An exercise about pullback morphism between rings of regular functions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, affine-varieties

Fix a field $K$ of characteristic zero.
We are given the affine variety $X=V(y^2-x^2-x^3)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$ and the morphism $f:\mathbb{A}^1\rightarrow X$ given by $t\mapsto ((t^2-1),t(t^2-1))$ and we are asked to show that the pullback $f*:\mathscr{O}(X)\rightarrow K[t]$ maps isomoprhically $\mathscr{O}(X)$ in the subring $S$ of $K[t]$ made by $\{g(t)\in K[t]\mid g(1)=g(-1)\}$.

I know little about how to deal with morphisms between algebras of which we know the presentation, but I think the image will be generated by the images of the generator, modulo the image of the relator, hence it will have generators $\{(t^2-1),t(t^2-1)\}$ and the relation $(t-1)^3(t+1)^4=0$, the fact is I do not know how to show, if this is the true image, that it coincides with $S$.

Comment: Excuse me very much. But $K$ is a generic field $\Bbb K$?

Comment: Yes, a field of characteristic 0, so I thought in C, and made a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is affine, we have $\mathscr{O}(X) = K[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3)$. The map $f^\ast \colon K[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3) \rightarrow K[t] $ is defined  by $f^\ast(x) = t^2-1$ and $f^\ast(y) = t(t^2-1)$. Hence for any $p(x,y) \in  K[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3)$ we have $$f^\ast p(t) = p\left(t^2-1, t(t^2-1) \right) = p(0,0) + (t^2-1)q(t)$$
In particular, $f^\ast p(t) \in S$ and we will show that $f^\ast\colon \mathscr{O}(X)\rightarrow S$ is an isomorphism.

By the first isomorphism theorem we only have to prove that the image of $f^\ast$ is $S$

Let $p(t) \in S$. By the division algorithm $p(t) = p_1(t)(t^2-1) + b_0$. As $p_1(t) = p_2(t)(t^2-1) +a_1t+b_1$ we have 
$$
p(t) =  p_2(t)(t^2-1)^2 +(a_1t+b_1)(t^2-1) +b_0
$$
Iterating this process we show that $p(t) = q\left(t^2-1, t(t^2-1) \right)$ hence $p(t)$ is the image of (the class of) $q(x,y)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Maybe it is implicit in your argument, but shouldn't we check that the kernel of the map $p(x,y)\in K[x,y]\mapsto p((t^2-1),t(t^2-1)) \in K[t]$ has kernel $I=(y^2-x^2-x^3)$, to apply the homomorphism theorem? More generally, if we have a finetely generated algebra $R$ I know we can present it by $K[x_1,...,x_n]/I$, for some $I$. Now, if we have a morphism from this algebra to another, as in this case, how can we present its image? I mean, will it be generated by the image of the generators modulo something?

Comment: Yes, I skipped that part. We can use the division algorithm $p(x,y)  = q(x,y)(y^2-x^3-x^2) + r(x)y+s(x)$ and show that $f^\ast p = 0$ iff $r=s=0$.